# How many SSL certificates I must buy in a service oriented system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, certificate

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know some information in order to buy SSL certificates.

I have a RoR application at this URL

```
pjtnam.com
```

and another RoR application at this URL

```
users.pjtname.com
```

If I make an HTTPS request from the application `pjtname.com` to the application `users.pjtname.com` like this (in this example I use the [Typhoeus gem](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus))

```
Typhoeus::Request.get(https://users.pjtname.com/sign_in)
```

and I must receive the response over HTTPS protocoll, **how many SSL certificates I must buy?**

---

**UPDATE**

*How many SSL certificates I must buy if*

1. my `pjtname.com` and `users.pjtname.com` applications are located on different server?
2. my applications are `pjtname1.com` and `pjtname2.com` and they are located on different server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If done properly, just one; a wildcard certificate for '*.pjtname.com' and 'pjtname.com' (it's possible to include more than one name in a single certificate).

While you could instead get a certificate for 'pjtname.com' and 'users.pjtname.com', such a certificate would no longer be sufficient when you later decide you need a 'mail.pjtname.com' or a 'chat.pjtname.com' or whatever.  The wildcard would cover these future cases.

**re: update**

1. It doesn't matter if services are located on different servers; just put the certificate on both servers.
2. It's possible to have both 'foo.com' and 'bar.com' in a single certificate, just like you can have both 'pjtname.com' and 'users.pjtname.com'.  However, it might more difficult to acquire  the foo/bar certificate than the pjtname.com/users.pjtname.com.

Also, these answers are true regardless of platform.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question for some other cases. Please, can you give me those other information?

Comment: What do you mean with "these answers are true regardless of platform"?

Comment: "I am using Ruby on Rails 3"... the answer is the same if you were using Java, C#, whathaveyou.